# Проблемы запуска Apache

Tags: apache, кодировка

Помогите, пожалуйста.

У меня apache работает через раз (работаю на denwer). Когда не запускается, тогда apache на 30 секунд открывает это (и еще меня интересуют кракозябры).

http://imagepost.ru/?v=zwddzkiskpezehaalapbuyzalpdibu.png

Я так и не могу понять закономерность, когда он запускается, а когда нет.

Comment: 80 порт свободен я с помощью netstat  проверил
объясните мне кракозябры  http://imagepost.ru/?v=zwddzkiskpezehaalapbuyzalpdibu.png

Answer (score 1):

Ясным языком же написано что порт 80 уже используется, это не в Денвере дело) Вообще XAMPP данному товарищу противопоказан, потому что имеет слишком много шар которые он врятли сам сможет закрыть.

Answer (score 1):

Все правильно, 80й порт уже кем-то занят. Чаще всего это скайп) В его настройках есть какая-то галочка, разрешающая скайпу слушать 80й порт, ее надо снять.

Answer (score 0):

Точно не уверен но у меня apache только один раз в жизни ругался. Когда я его хотел поверх другого апача пустить :D (причём так же через раз запускался)... Возможно у вас такая же проблема. К примеру обновили не правильно денвер. Совета 2 либо сносите денвер и ставьте опять либо выносите то что ему мешает работать ( к примеру XAMPP или свою сборку ).

Comment: Ещё третий совет - сносите Денвер и ставьте XAMPP а если есть уже то им пользуйтесь...меньше головомоек...